# Field resolvers in com.example.NewsPlus.News.GraphQLConfig required a bean of type 'java.util.List' that could not be found

Tags: spring, graphql, graphql-java

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-20 10:31:39.806 ERROR 6632 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field resolvers in com.example.NewsPlus.News.GraphQLConfig required a bean of type 'java.util.List' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.util.List' in your configuration.

> Task :NewsPlus.main() FAILED
> 3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':NewsPlus.main()'.

> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

solve this problem